# How to extract small portion of GIS database from entire database

Tags: spatial-database

Is it possible to extract a small portion of data from an entire database? If possible then how can I do it. I want data to be extracted which is within my map view only, so that other data objects are excluded: only objects contained in the map view should be in the extract.

Comment: what software are you using? Is this desktop GIS or on the web? More info required

Comment: Just to clarify, by "contained in" do you mean the features fall entirely within the current extent, or that they _overlap_ the current extent?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming from `GIS database` and `map view` that you are using ArcGIS.

If so the below steps could help.

1. Activate the Distributed Geodatabase toolbar.
   [image: Dsitributed Geodatabase Toolbar]
2. Zoom to the map view you want.
3. Click the extract Data button.
4. Select Show Advanced Options
   [image]
5. Enable Current Display extent.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am using GE Smallworld GIS and I want the small portion of data to be extracted as Datastore file so that using that DS file I can open new image...Please suggest method for this.

Comment: I just want spatial extraction(extract for network objects) process

Answer (score 0):

As with your other question, you've failed to specify which database you're using and the SQL will vary a bit between databases. I'll leave others to deal with this aspect.

Given you're apparently using FME [(per your other question)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23228/can-we-use-fme-translator-for-upgrading-lower-version-gis-database-into-higher-v), you can use that to do it in a couple of ways:

a) Once you've added the reader you can specify Maximum x,y and minimum x,y as parameters and the reader will only select features within those bounds. That creates a square bounding box.

b) Alternately you can pass the data through a **SpatialFilter** and check against a shape of your given area. Use the "INTERSECTS" test.